# Deriving the equation for the length of focal chord of parabola inclined at an angle $\alpha$

Tags: conic-sections

[image]

The parametric coordinates for the line AB would be $(a+ r\cos\alpha, r\sin\alpha)$.

Let's put this coordinates in the equation $y^2=4ax$.

We get, $r^2\sin^2\alpha - 4a\cos\alpha r -4a^2=0$

Sum of roots=AB= $\frac{-b}{a}=\frac{4a\cos\alpha}{(\sin\alpha)^2}$

But the right answer is AB=$\frac{4a}{(\sin\alpha)^2}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because the roots have opposite signs, you don't want their *sum*, you want (the absolute value of) their *difference*.

Comment: Extending comment of Blue: $(y_1-y_2)^2=(y_1+y_2)^2-4y_1y_2$.